# Auto Rest API Client Visual Studio no retry on failure

Tags: c#, .net, rest, swagger

I have a problem with the handling of the Rest Api Client that i created directly in visual studio based on my swagger api. **("Add" -> Rest Api Client")** (C#)

When a request fails, the client tries 5 times before finally throwing the exception.

How can i make sure that the client will throw the exception directly without the retries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use fiddler to check requests from your client . https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: i know fiddler but this is not the thing i asked for. i would like to know how to avoid that the created client retries on failure

Comment: that's great, fiddler is a web debugging proxy, now you're supposed to know how to trigger your retry, in this scenario, you'll use fiddler to intercept the request, if you only have one request it means that the retry does work. luck

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this if you create a partial class of the generated swagger client.  Be sure to match the namespace of the generated client in your implementation.  Create an empty constructor and set the retry policy.

```
namesapce <Generated Client Namespace>
{
    public partial class MyClient
    {
        public MyClient()
        {
            this.SetRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(new ErrorRetryStrategy(), 0));
        }
    }
}
```

the 0 represents a retry count.  On top of that the definition of retry strategy always returns a false so that short circuits a retry.

you will also need to implement an ErrorRetryStrategy()

```
public class ErrorRetryStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

an alternative implementation would be to customize the return.

```
public class RetryStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
            return ex is HttpRequestException;
    }
}
```